# How can i speed up a very slow MongoDB query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I'm executing a MongoDB bulk write query on a loop of around 300 json records each time. I have an `update()` function and a list, for each element in the list `update()` is called and every execution should execute a bulk write query of 300 upsert queries.

Here is a simplified version of my code, in order to make it easier to read:

```
MyList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...]

def update():
    Queries = 
       [
          [{'Unix': 1596873600.0, 'market': 'TEST'}, {'$set': {'Unix': 1596873600.0, 'O': '11586.08000000', 'H': '11801.72000000', 'L': '11562.17000000', 'C': '11775.52000000', 'V': '9066.55659000', 'market': 'TEST'}, 'upsert': True}], 
          [{'Unix': 1596888000.0, 'market': 'TEST'}, {'$set': {'Unix': 1596888000.0, 'O': '11775.52000000', 'H': '11808.27000000', 'L': '11706.39000000', 'C': '11738.10000000', 'V': '6628.24686700', 'market': 'TEST'}, 'upsert': True}],
          ... 
       ] #Total length is 300
    
    db['myCol'].bulk_write(Queries)


for x in MyList:
    update()
```

The problem with this code is that each call of `update()` takes too much time to execute; not only, the execution time increases while `MyList` is looped.

So at first it will take around 1 second for every query, but it will increase to up to 3/4 seconds for a query midway through the list. Now, there are two problems here: isn't one second already too much for a bulk operation of 300 documents? And why does the execution time increase to up to 3/4 seconds?

Here are some more details:

1. I'm keeping track of the time it takes with a simple `print(f'Time: {end - start}')`
2. `Unix` and `market` are indexes
3. The database that i'm querying is hosted on a different server, not my local machine.

Is this execution time normal? How can i speed this up? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you use Compound Indexes https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/ then come back here if it didn't help

Comment: I am not familiar with python, however it looks like you run the same upsert many times again and again: once by `bulk_write` and another times by `for x in MyList: update()`.

Comment: @DanielF the exec time seems to be now around 0.9 and 1.3 second, so it's an improvement! I'm now trying to check why each query takes so much time

Comment: Make sure you have the compound index with the fields in the correct sorting order, this is important. If you can't improve it, there is still the `oredered=False` option in the  `bulk_write` method. This will speed up the inserts, but your `_id` field will no longer represent the order of the documents in the array you're inserting.

Comment: Also, are you sure you need to use `upsert`? I mean, what you are doing here is you're querying the DB for each record you're inserting ("please update the record, and if it doesn't exist, insert it"). If you know that you are inserting unique records, where none is supposed to overwrite another one, you don't need to search for them, you simply insert them, which is a lot faster.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Unfortunately i'm almost sure i'm forced to use upsert. Basically this will run as a first job that, on the first run will fill an empty collection, so in that case it would be a simple insert, but on the next runs it will need to update and when a document is not found, insert it

Comment: One more thing: what happens when the index is a string and it's the same for a number of documents, in this case it doesn't change whether the order is ascending or descending, right?